# How to add clear shopping cart button in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart

How to add clear shopping cart button in Magento 2

In [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184745/55981) I added in minicart but I want it in cart page.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear Shopping Cart button is hidden by CSS.

[image]

Comment: It was hidden in css, Now tell me how do i enable it

Answer (score 2):

There is system configuration for this you just need to enable from the admin panel.
[image]

**Note : I am using magento2.4.6**

Answer (score 1):

There is s style.css in Pub>media folder add
.cart-container .form-cart .actions.main .clear {
    display: inline-table !important;
}