# How to clear cart and minicart programatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart, delete

How to clear cart and minicart programatically in Magento 2??
I am using this code

```
$quoteId = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();
$quoteModel = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote');
$quoteItem = $quoteModel->load($quoteId);
$quoteItem->delete();
```

this clears cart but minicart items are still showing.. Can anyone please help me to fix this issue??
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mini cart items are from browser local storage. That means you need to reload the frontend cart section as well. An example here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184745/33057

Comment: I have redirected to cart page after item delete.. but still it is not working..

Comment: Make sure the cart section reloaded as well.

Comment: You just want to empty cart ? Is it the case

Comment: yes, I want to empty the cart as well as minicart

Comment: Thank you so much @Khoa TruongDinh.. I have reloaded cart section using your above link, and it is working..

Comment: Hello @Khoa TruongDinh. Did you know any event which is call before minicart load ?

Answer (score 3):

May be this code will help your logic :

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $cartObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart')->truncate();
 $cartObject->saveQuote();
```

Remember that section is loaded after execution above code .

Answer (score -1):

Currently on Magento 2.3.0 this code executed on backend will empty your cart and mini-cart:

```
$cart->truncate()->save();
```

Where $cart is an instance of \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart.