# M2.2: Using REST API, Can Clear Cart but Mini-Cart Not Clearing

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api, shopping-cart, mini-cart

We are currently integrating another checkout portal to go on top of our existing Magento 2 platform. They are using the REST API to do most of their calls to Magento 2, including that of clearing the cart. When clearing the cart on the portal, it will clear it fully, and when coming back to the Magento 2 side, the cart will be empty, however the Mini-Cart will still be populated with all the items that we're previously there before being cleared.

They are using the specific endpoint:

```
DELETE method : rest/V1/carts/mine/items/#ITEM_ID#
```

However they have not found any other means of clearing the cart, and using the above results in the mentioned issue of the mini cart still being populated.

I have done a [little research](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210945/how-to-clear-cart-and-minicart-programatically-in-magento-2) and found that it appears the mini-cart information stays due to being stored in local storage. It is mentioned to try using;

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cartObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart')->truncate();
$cartObject->saveQuote();
```

or

```
$cart->truncate()->save();
Where $cart is an instance of \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart.
```

However I wouldn't know where to make those above changes, nor aware if that will achieve the result of having both carts emptied when they use the DELETE method endpoint. Is there a different method I should have them use to clear both the cart and mini-cart while just having access to the REST API endpoints? Or something I can change on my end that will clear it for them when the endpoint is called, like hooking into the above API method and truncate the mini-cart from the Magento 2 code?

---

**UPDATE - 10/26**

The full process goes as follows:

From our Magento 2 webstore, the customer adds products to the cart and when they click the 'Proceed to checkout' button, it will redirect to the new portal (leaving magento 2 to their platform).

On the new portal, they use the API below to get the cart:

API endpoint: /rest/V1/carts/mine

Parameters to pass:
[{"key":"Authorization","value":"Bearer vm3pful29u7ywxfdsfsadsa1414"}]

Here, the value should be the token returned by the customer login API.

API Response: Returns all the info from the M2 cart.

They only add products to the cart if they exist in their portal as well. If there are any products that do not exist in their portal, they show a message noting it on the portal and provide a link to go back to the Magento 2 site.

Assuming they have products in the portal and get the cart item there, once they place a successful order from the new portal, the portal calls the below API to delete the cart items of the Magento 2:

DELETE : rest/V1/carts/mine/items/#ITEM_ID#

Here the method is DELETE and they have to pass the item IDs to delete the cart from Magento 2.

---

They go on to mention:

"If you are asking regarding the API code files in Magento 2, we would need to research that. We don't have code access of Magento 2, but these are Magento 2 default inbuilt APIs and we are using that."

So knowing the above, is it possible with the default inbuilt APIs to do what we are asking? (Not just deleting from the cart but the mini-cart as well) or is there more we will need to get into to achieve that?

---

**UPDATE - 10/29**

Below are the exact file locations/complete contents within the created **Custom_MinicartRefresh** (in reference to @Sony 's answer) -- does anything look amiss that I am just not seeing for this to not be working?

/app/code/Custom/MinicartRefresh/**registration.php**

```php
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Custom_MinicartRefresh', __DIR__);
```

/app/code/Custom/MinicartRefresh/etc/**module.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_MinicartRefresh" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

/app/code/Custom/MinicartRefresh/view/frontend/web/**requirejs-config.js**

```javascript
var config = {
    deps: ['Custom_MinicartRefresh/js/minicart-refresh'],
};
```

/app/code/Custom/MinicartRefresh/view/frontend/web/js/**minicart-refresh.js**

```javascript
define([
        "jquery",
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
        'domReady!'
    ], function ($, customerData) {
        "use strict";
        var sections = ['cart'];
        console.log('cart checked');
            setInterval(function () {
                    customerData.invalidate(sections);
                    customerData.reload(sections, true);
            }, 3000);
    }
)
```

That is all, and I have done the steps of Development mode within Cloudflare, and;

- setup:upgrade
- setup:di:compile
- setup:static-content:deploy -f
- indexer:reindex
- cache:flush

All to no avail, is there something obvious I am just missing? Thanks!

Comment: what steps you will be following? add to cart from API, review the cart item from the desktop web app, then remove the item from API, again reviewing the cart from a desktop web app? why I asking because API is mostly used for communicating with third party app.

Comment: do they still have access to layout and requirejs. can you post the files where the cart API call is made to give us an idea where we are when this call is performed? don't need all the details, just the file name and where is sits in the system I guess should be sufficient

Comment: Appreciate the assistance guys! @Nits I updated the question with a workflow of how they are interacting with our store.

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy I updated the post with their workflow, I don't believe they have direct access to the files (of course I could make edits for them if that is whats required) but their initial access is just the default API endpoints

Comment: They don't happen to use the same subdomain ? In that case there are ways to manipulate the local storage directly.

Comment: @Kristoffer No they don't they are on separate subdomain (may change in future, but this is how it is for now), if that maintains as the case, what do you think would be best way to manipulate the local storage to clear the cart here?

Comment: An easy one-line would be: 
window.localStorage.setItem("mage-cache-storage", []); You can test it in your console and then you will notice that your minicart is cleared. However if you decide to go with this solution you have to take a more finegrained approach and only remove the parts in local storage you wish to remove...

Comment: @Kristoffer Thanks for this! Is there a way to skim through the different localStorage items inside your console to designate the specific mini cart ones? And also, is there a way, possibly via JS to see if your actual cart is empty or not, which could proc this type of call?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to clear the mini cart you need to invalidate the section and then to reload it.

To achieve that, usually we go through the JS, and it looks something like that :

```
define(['jquery','Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function ($, customerData) {
        "use strict";
        var sections = ['cart'];
        customerData.invalidate(sections);
        customerData.reload(sections, true);
        }
);
```

The thing is that the mini-cart is in the browser local storage, and you need to refresh it.

But since you don't have any access to the Magento 2 code... it seems quite hard to achieve what you what.

EDIT :

If you are able to load a new Magento module here is the code

Let's say that your module is called `MinicartRefresh` and your vendor name is `MyNamespace`

`app/code/MyNamespace/MinicartRefresh/etc`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyNamespace_MinicartRefresh" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

`app/code/MyNamespace/MinicartRefresh/view/frontend/web/js/minicart-refresh.js`

```
define([
        "jquery",
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
        'domReady!'
    ], function ($, customerData) {
        "use strict";
        var sections = ['cart'];
            setInterval(function () {
                    customerData.invalidate(sections);
                    customerData.reload(sections, true);
            }, 3000);
    }
)
```

The minicart should be refreshed every 3s , feel free to change the time.

`app/code/MyNamespace/MinicartRefresh/view/frontend/web/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    deps: ['MyNamespace_MinicartRefresh/js/minicart-refresh'],
};
```

`app/code/MyNamespace/MinicartRefresh/registration.php`

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'MyNamespace_MinicartRefresh', __DIR__);
```

After upload the module , run `php bin/magento s:up` , `php bin/magento s:d:c` and clear cache and all the stuff you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I actually run the Magento 2 side of this whole interaction, though I don't know all sides of it just yet which is why I came here. If there are magento 2 files that I would need to edit to include such a function, I can do that. My question would just be what files to allow for such a thing?

Comment: Are you able to create a module ? have you any ssh access or only ftp ? can you run some command line ?

Comment: I am indeed able of loading a module (via ftp or any means) along with running the ssh commands. I essentially have full control of all the Magento side

Comment: @ne0nlight I have edited the answer , and gave you the code that you would need.

Comment: Thanks! I will get to trying this now. As I understand, it really pays no attention to the REST API work at all, it essentially jus just checking the cart every 3 seconds, and if the actual cart ends up being empty (and the mini cart continues to have products) it will continue checking and once the 3 second check sees the actual cart is empty, it will clear the mini cart as well. Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it should work. I have done it for one of my projects already.

Comment: So I created the module, enabled it, and did the setup:upgrade, di:compile, static-content:deploy, index:reindex, and cache:flush (all while having Cloudflare in development mode so no cache issues should really be there), everything seemed fine however I added `console.log('cart checked');` inside the Interval function to see if it was firing off and checking the cart, however I am not seeing anything in the console. Is there a way to verify it is doing the check? (The other team hasn't renabled the option to empty the cart on their side yet for me to verify if it fully works just yet or not)

Comment: Can you show me where did you put the `console.log` ?  I assume you have refreshed the cache after putting the console.log .  I have put console.log as well when I created the module, and the console.log was showed :)

Comment: I inserted it like so; `setInterval(function () { customerData.invalidate(sections); customerData.reload(sections, true); console.log('cart checked'); }, 3000);` and I've had it in development mode and cleared the cache, still getting no console alerts. Would there be any added parts to include in any of the files?

Comment: As a side note, would I be able to just bring that function (with the jquery and customerdata loading) to an already active js file and it'd work the same way in that respect?

Comment: which active js file ? it's an existing custom file or you want to write one of magento core js file ?  The thing for this, is that you need to be sure that this file is called on every page. The code that I gave you, call the Js file on every page. Are you able to check the `app/etc/config.php` file ? and check if the MinicartRefresh module is enable ?  I don't see any problem with your current console.log , it should work.

Comment: The active file I was going to use was `Magento_Customer/templates/account/customer.phtml`, but when doing so, it did show the console log message as intended, however after a little bit it ended up throwing 500 errors and ended up crashing the page. When going inside `app/etc/config.php` I have `'Custom_MinicartRefresh' => 1,` and double checking all the files, I've updated all the spots of `MyNamespace/MinicartRefresh` to `Custom/MinicartRefresh`, but still for whatever reason the logging doesn't appear

Comment: put your `console.log` under `var sections = ['cart'];` and check if it appears. If not, that means that your js is not called in the page. You can check it in your browser by opening the inspector, network tab, filter by js and look for the minicart-refresh.js file

Comment: You are correct, I moved it under the variable and have now noticed that the actual file is not being called. Is there a way to try and determine what could be amiss? I copied all the files mentioned above, the config.php says it's enabled.. not sure what I could have done wrong?

Comment: I added to the original question how my files are, is anything glaringly missing?? Thanks!

Comment: I was able to get this working with a few changes to the files, however it seems to throw errors when a customer isn't logged in. Is there a way to have this check if they are logged in first, and if so, then do the 3 second interval check?

Comment: what is the error ? Also what did you changes in the files ? :) With this code, in theory it's not matter if the customer is logged or not.

Comment: I think the main issue I had, was having the requirejs inside the `frontend/web/` folder instead of just the `frontend` folder, the other file edits we're mainly just little things like using `<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(` instead of `<?php use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;` -- that said, the error I was experiencing seems to have solved itself and it is working as intended now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

@sony's answer was what I had in mind for you.

It seems it needs to be something else than API. The closest I have for you is for this external system to perform an ajax call to your magento site. This call would trigger the javascript Sony points out and this would clear the localstorage for you.

So, once the ajax cart call is successful, you would reload your page. If this is doable (MEANING: can your external system's partner confirm it is possible to trigger some javascript rather than API call??), I (and many of us, race on!) can come up with the module with ajax code.

Comment: I believe this should be possible, I run the magento side so any file editing or including new modules, etc that would need to be done magento side, I can implement, and then just inform them what to call during their API interactions. Would that work?

Comment: I am still unsure whether your partner can perform some javascript on their system and within this javascript, it would need to perform a cross domain query to magento

Comment: They are not able to do javascript through the API. When using a REST API, they can only send the request to the API endpoint and then the Magento code takes all of the information from the request and handles it from there. That is where the module Sony has suggested may have to be the play

Comment: agreed, Sony has done already a great job and seems to be on the right track, please follow his lead, many thanks for your update