# How to clear item in cart in frontend web page programmatically?

Tags: magento2.2, frontend, shopping-cart, quoteitem, cart-items

Using magento 2.2, I need to **remove** all items in current cart while going to other **root category** on my front page. I want some advice for coding this event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delete cart items using below code.

```
public function deleteQuoteItems()
{
  $checkoutSession = $this->getCheckoutSession();
  $allItems = $checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

    foreach ($allItems as $item) {
     $itemId = $item->getItemId();//item id of particular item
     $quoteItem=$this->getItemModel()->load($itemId);
     $quoteItem->delete();//deletes the item
    }
}



 public function getCheckoutSession()
 {
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();//instance of object manager 
  $checkoutSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');//checkout session

  return $checkoutSession;
 }

public function getItemModel()
{
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();//instance of object manager
 $itemModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item');//Quote item model to load quote item

  return $itemModel;
}
```

MiniCart is rendering using **Local Storage**.

To clear it check here.  Very Well Explained.
[How to add "Empty Cart" button to minicart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184501/how-to-add-empty-cart-button-to-minicart/184745#184745)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below script to delete cartItems.

root/scripts/clearCartItem.php

```
    <?php


    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

    $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    try {
        $checkoutSession = $obj->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
        $cart = $obj->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');


        $allItems = $checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($allItems as $item) {
            $itemId = $item->getItemId();
            $cart->removeItem($itemId)->save();
        }

        echo "Cleared all items in cart";
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```